# How to show Only 4 slides in a row using Bxslider

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have Bxslider on my page and two  sliders

First here and in works great

[image: Top Slider]

Second here is bottom slider

[image: bottom slider]

It makes more and more rows (since i add new items to slider), but all i need is that it will show only 4 slides in a single row (i don't need another rows).

Here how it looks in code

```
<div class="popular-slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <div class="popular">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular1.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 1</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular2.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 2</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular3.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 3</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular4.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 4</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular4.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 5</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular4.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 6</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/popular4.jpg"><br>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#">Item text 7</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here what I have in css

```
.main-content .popular {
  background: #fff;
}
.main-content .popular .item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-content .popular .item:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.main-content .popular .item p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.main-content .popular .item p a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #414a56;
}
```

Here is my bxslider code

```
$(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    speed: 500
  });
});
```

Comment: Please include the pictures in the post instead of linking to another site for them. This makes the question useful to the site as it doesn't rely on external links which can disappear. As it is this question would be classified as unclear and closed. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi Trevor, thank you for your advice, but i'm new here, and system says that i cannot attach screens, it will show only links. Thank you.

Comment: I've done an edit for you to include the pictures. Just waiting for it to go through which should be soon (hopefully).  Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Changes

1. The reason why your slider was showing so many slides is because you assigned the bxSlider to a `<ul>` that had only one huge `<li>`. To fix this:

   - Removed `<ul class="bxslider">` and `<li>`
   - Reassigned bxSlider plugin to `<div class="popular">`
   - Designated each `<div class="item">` as a slide. See [`slideSelector`](http://bxslider.com/options#slideSelector)
2. In CSS `.main-content` is used, yet in the HTML there is a `.popular-slider`. I changed `<div class="popular-slider">` to `<div class="main-content">`. Without this fix, none of your CSS would work.
3. Used the following bxSlider options in order to display 4 slides at a time:

   - [`minSlides: 4`](http://bxslider.com/options#minSlides)  Lock the number of slides by...
   - [`maxSlides: 4`](http://bxslider.com/options#minSlides)  ...assigning the same number to...
   - [`moveSlides: 4`](http://bxslider.com/options#moveSlides) ...these three options. In your case, it's 4.
   - [`slideWidth: 200`](http://bxslider.com/options#slideWidth) ...When you create a carousel (a slider showing more than one slide at a time), you are required to specify the width of a single slide by using the `slideWidth` option.
   - There's one more thing that's not very obvious about carousels you should be aware of. Use this simple rule when determining the number of slides you'll need: divide the total you plan to have by the number of slides you intend to display at a time. If the result is a whole number (e.g. 1, 2, 3...), then it's ok. In your case you should have 4 (but that's boring), 8, 12, 16, 20... The reason why is if your carousel had 7 slides (I added the 8th slide), then it wouldn't stop or pause on the slides consistently:

     - 1st move: slide 5 is now in the first position
     - 2nd move: slide 2 is now in the first position
     - 3rd move: slide 6 is now in the first position

## Snippet

```js
$(function() {
  $('.popular').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    autoControls: true,
    speed: 500,
    slideSelector: 'div.item',
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4,
    moveSlides: 4,
    slideWidth: 200


  });
});
```

```css
.main-content .popular {
  background: #fff;
}
.main-content .popular .item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-content .popular .item:after {
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.main-content .popular .item p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.main-content .popular .item p a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #414a56;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-content">

  <div class="popular">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/nature">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 1</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/arch">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 2</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/nature">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 3</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/arch">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 4</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/nature">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 5</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/arch">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 6</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/nature">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 7</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/150/arch">
      <br>
      <p>
        <a href="#">Item text 8</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great! Please accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark, otherwise this answer may get buried and unnoticed. People that have the same problem that you had might not have the opportunity to benefit from this answer in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Write in js:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 2,
  maxSlides: 2,
  slideWidth: 360,
  slideMargin: 10
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some slight tweaks to your HTML structure. Please see below:

```
<div class="popular-slider bx-viewport">
<div class="bx-controls-direction"><a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a></div>
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular1.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 1</a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular2.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 2</a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular3.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 3</a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular4.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 4</a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular4.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 5</a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular4.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 6</a> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="popular">
            <div class="item"> <img src="img/popular4.jpg">
                <br>
                <p> <a href="#">Item text 7</a> </p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul></div>
```

There need to be a small value change in the bxslider JS file :

```
// CAROUSEL
    minSlides: 4,
    maxSlides: 4,
    moveSlides: 4,
    slideWidth: 300,
```

Adjust your slideWidth value as per your layout. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, I have made some improvements based on your code, but now have another problem. Now is don't show all items, but shows white screen. http://joxi.ru/l2ZvjMbS8wJQ42 and http://joxi.ru/nAyz5QkfXYJlYr

Comment: @ildar The reason why it's showing a blank is because you have 7 items and you are showing 4 slides at a time. See my answer for details.